# How to create a CSV file with linebreaks and quotations marks?

Tags: java, csv, escaping

In my Java application, I'm going to write a CSV file with various columns. Some of these columns contain source code and therefore linebreaks, quotation marks and other special characters.

I'm running into the problem that this destroys the structure of my CSV file. I tried to mitigate this problem by using the method escapeCsv from the StringEscapeUtils class like that:

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv(getId().toString()) + ", " + StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv(dateFormat.format(getTimestamp()));
```

But still, the linebreaks and quotation marks in the source code destroys the structure of my CSV file. What else can I do?

Comment: not use a CSV file maybe ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`OpenCSV`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) library instead of `StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a library to make it easy to deal with. You have for example

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

or

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/